# how to get correct data display from json

Tags: jquery, json

i have my json sent from the php file as

```
echo json_encode(array('uname'=>$fname,'Oname'=>$pi['name'],'osize'=>$size));
```

iam looping through it on the client side with the following jquery,but it does not display all records in the list.how can i make it work effectively

```
function work(i,fly,response){
var cookedJSON=[];cookedJSON.push({ uname : response.uname , Oname : response.Oname , osize :response.osize });
             _outfilenames=[];
    $.each(cookedJSON, function(i,arr) {

          _outfilenames.push("<li id='group_0_file_"+i+"'class='image-list'>" +"<div class='controls' title='remove file'><a href='#' class='image-list' data-filename='"+arr.uname +"'><img src='stop.png' ></a></div>"+   "<span class='filename'>" +arr.Oname+ "</span> "  +"<span class='details'>size:</strong>"+arr.osize +" </span>" +"</li>");//}
    });  // close each()
    $(_outfilenames.join('')).appendTo(f_list);
```

what am i doing wrong and what can I do to put it right????

Comment: Did you try to add `console.log` and check how do you get the JSON from the server?

Comment: iam going to try it right now

Comment: where can i find that console.log.i do not have firebug

Comment: you can use developer tools in Chrome

Comment: Iam using firefox and knownothing about developer tools

Answer (score 1):

Your `cookedJSON` is an array that stores only one JSON in it. To retrieve this JSON properties, you should use:

```java
cookedJSON[0].uname;
cookedJSON[0].oname;
cookedJSON[0].osize;
```

You may also use:

```java
cookedJSON[0]['uname'];
cookedJSON[0]['oname'];
cookedJSON[0]['osize'];
```

If you however use:

```java
cookedJSON.uname;
cookedJSON.oname;
cookedJSON.osize;
```

You would get `undefined` in the console log.

Comment: must be why the i variable wasn't changing from 0

Comment: how are you looping through cookedJSON??i tell you it is returning atleast 2 values in the list but not all as required.